# Can't get date to show in a text box

Tags: c#, winforms

Creating a Windows Forms Application in C#, I have a program that I am trying to insert a date into a text box (textBox3), and I can't get the date to show up. I created a button on the form that pops up, and the date shows up just fine. But, the text box never populates. Any suggestions? Here's the code:

```
    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var today = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        textBox3.Text = today;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var today = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        MessageBox.Show("Today is " + today + ".");
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand why you are modifying the Text value of the textbox in its TextChanged event?

Comment: Why are you trying to change text of the textbox which reports a change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text field will only update when you start typing anything on the textbox because, apparently, you are hooking up to the [Text_Changed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) event.

Type something in `textBox3` and you'll see that the text becomes whatever `today` is holding.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have **will only work** when you **type something on it**. The reason is that you are filling your Textbox.Text in the [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) event (when the user types something in the textbox).

What I guess you want to do is to assign the Text property after [InitializeComponent](http://www.dotnetperls.com/initializecomponent) in your form, or any other initialization stuff such as [FormLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx):

```
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeDates();            
    }

    public void InitializeDates()
    {
        var today = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        textBox3.Text = today;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, thanks to anyone that gave me a response without doing it in a question. I understand where the questions are directed, but they only confuse the already confused. I learn by doing things, so direct answers are GREATLY appreciated!

However, I got around the issue of needing to type in the field to have it populate the date, by pre-loading the text on load! So, Icarus you are correct. I wanted to assume the user might not type in the date box at all. (trying to make it failproof)

Thanks again, all!   :-)

```
 **private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)**
    {
         try
             {
                {
                textBox2.Text = "Date";
                }
                     {
                        catch (System.Exception ex)
                     }
                {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
             }
    }
```

The rest was easy . . .

```
   **private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)**
            {
                var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                textBox2.Text = date;
            }
```